# Trying to find a YA Paranormal Romance Graphic Novel Series from the 1990s

Tags: story-identification, comics, young-adult, vampire, werewolf

I'm trying to find a series of comics/graphic novels I read at the tail end of the 1990s.

The main character is a blond girl moving into a new house (I'm pretty sure it was a relative's house, and the relative was some sort of paranormal creature).  I seem to recall that she herself has something supernatural about her, but I can't recall if she's a vampire or witch, or if I'm mis-remembering.

There's also a romance plot involving a werewolf.  At one point there's a concert scene with a number of different supernatural creatures.